# How to use :PlugInstall intelligently

Tags: vimrc, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-vundle

I have installed YouCompleteMe in the past, but don't remember how. I recently decided to sync my `~.vim` directory over multiple computers via a cloud service and realized I was inadvertently downloading a huge amount of language support I didn't need. I attempted to manually clear (ir)relevantly-named subdirectories, and then noticed that the completion suggestions I needed (for LaTeX; it will become clear, if it is not already I am not any kind of programmer) had stopped functioning. I would like to reinstall it from scratch.

So, trying to follow the documentation for YouCompleteMe and one YouTube video, I've now done the following:

1. Deleted the `YouCompleteMe` directory from `~/.vim/plugins`,
2. Deleted the line `Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'` from my `.vimrc` and done `:w` and `:so %`,
3. Run `:PlugClean` (which reports that there is nothing to clean),
4. Readded the line `Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'`, done `:w` and `:so %` and `:PlugInstall`, which reports that there is nothing to be added.

I can do 3) and 4) in a loop indefinitely without anything changing, and `:PluginList` reports the installedness of YouCompleteMe whenever the line `Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'` is present in the `.vimrc` and `:so %` has been run, without any apparent installation having happened in between.

I am obviously doing something very simple very incorrectly. **What should I be doing instead?**

Comment: there might be files other than those in `~/.vim/plugins` (lots of (sub)directories in the `runtimepath`), and I think vim-plug keeps all its stuff in certain user-configured places.

Comment: So you'd recommend trying to hunt down and manually delete those files? Is what happened that the purge function doesn't know what to look for because I've already deleted the index?

Comment: yes I think so; best to start as clean as you can.